# How to insert a slider to home page on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm new on wordpress. Have an experience with Joomla. There I can create a module and insert it anywhere. How can I do it in worpdress? I created a slider using bx-slider on separate page. How can I get the code of the slider to insert it on index.php? 
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

**if you use the wordpress page then put following code on wordpress page**

```
[bxslider id="your slider id"]
```

**if you are put code on index.php so put following code on index.php**

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[bxslider id="your slider id"]'); ?>
```